# How to find amateur online sc2 tournaments?

Tags: starcraft-2

Sometimes it might be fun to enter a tournament every once in a while, but I don't really know where to start. How does one go about finding online amateur-level tournaments?

I am hoping for something like a simple news feed / calendar that links to upcoming public tournaments. I am hoping for something nice and accessible, and avoid having to "become involved with" a forum or community and spend a lot of time searching.

Basically something to supplement ladder play with a different dynamic, and a tangible end result.

Comment: This is something I am very interested in too, with divisions across multiple lower leagues.

Comment: weird i didn't realize you could open a bounty on someone else's question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Team Liquid has a list of tournaments: http://www.teamliquid.net/tournaments/

Comment: This single page does answer the question most specifically. I just wish there were more 'weekend warrior' type events. Something akin to 7/5 a-side soccer, amateur but competitive weekly tournies but for those less inclined to physical activity.

Answer (score 12):

Z33K has a lot of tournaments going on:

http://www.z33k.com/starcraft2/tournaments/

http://www.z33k.com/starcraft2/community_tournaments

Teamliquid has a listing:
http://www.teamliquid.net/tournaments/

Binary Beast has a bunch:
http://binarybeast.com/tourney/list/public

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like z33k shut down

Answer (score 3):

You can try out either [Sc2-tournament.com](http://sc2-tournament.com) - they host amateur tournaments only so far.

Also Playhem.com

Answer (score 2):

For European tournaments (mostly in French) you can use [Wannawar.com](http://www.wannawar.com/base.php?rub=site/tournoi_calendar.php)
They are lots of amateur-level tournaments but also decent good-level tournaments.

However, I believe Wannawar don't host non European tournaments ATM.

Answer (score 2):

One Idea that worked very well is starting up a local tournament at my company.

For an amateur trying to break into the scene there are many high level tournaments (for example [Gosu Coaching](http://www.gosucoaching.com) holds a weekly tournament, as does [US Craft Cup](http://www.bitsperbeat.com/ussc2/)), but frequently for amateur players these are out of their skill range.

Instead, if you take the time to organize a tournament at you company you may quickly find a tournament more your caliber.  What's more you can even form some sort of after hours gaming league where you compete against other companies.

---

I wasn't allowed to discuss this before, but we did (with the help of Day9) set up an [After Hours Gaming League](http://afterhoursgaming.tv/), where I do participate in show matches.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few sites that run there own amateur tournaments as you are probably aware of by now. For European tournaments in English, http://www.n00bgaming.com is good. You can also challenge people in a 1v1 for a wager on there. It's a new site though so not that many members yet.

Answer (score 0):

ESL has weekly tournaments for [bronze/silver](http://beta.esl.eu/eu/sc2/1on1/bronzesilver) and [gold/platinum](http://beta.esl.eu/eu/sc2/1on1/goldplatinum).